# How to make a confirm box appear when user closes or refreshes page

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

so I'm making a drawing app. the problem is, when the user accidentally closes or refreshes the page, all the drawings will be lost. So I made a confirmation box that will confirm if the user really wants to close the page.

I have tried like this:

```
if (window.onbeforeunload == true ) {
confirm("Change are still not saved. Are you sure?")
}
```

But it doesn't work. Then what is the best solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onbeforeunload` is a function which is called when leaving the page. So you have to define it.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
    return "Change are still not saved. Are you sure?";
};
```

Comment: don't you need `event.preventDefault();` ?